# Number of time the iterative function is called

Tags: c++, algorithm, fibonacci

Would like to seek a bit of help from StackOverflow. I am trying to print out the sequence of Fibonacci number and also the number of time the iterative function is called which is supposed to be `5` if the input is `5`.

However, I am only getting `4199371` as a count which is a huge number and I am trying to solve the problem since four hours. Hope anyone who could spot some mistake could give a hint.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fibIterative(int);

int main() 
{
    int num, c1;
    cout <<  "Please enter the number of term of fibonacci number to be displayed: ";
    cin  >> num;

    for (int x = 0; x <= num; x++) 
    {
        cout << fibIterative(x);

        if (fibIterative(x) != 0) {
            c1++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << "Number of time the iterative function is called: " << c1 << endl;
}

int fibIterative(int n) 
{
   int i = 1;
   int j = 0;
   for(int k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
       j = i + j;
       i = j - i;     
   }
   return j;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to initialize `c1`.

Comment: I encourage you to use a debugger. It's an important problem solving tool and I think you would have found the error quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, initialize the variable

```
c1 = 0;
```

so that you will not get any garbage value get printed.

---

Secondly this:

```
if (fibIterative(x) != 0)
{
     c1++;
}
```

will make `2*count - 1` your count. You don't need that.

**Edit**: I have noticed that you have removed extra `c1++;` from your [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51583320/1). Hence, the above problem is not more valid. However, you are calling the function `fibIterative()` again to have a check, which is not a good idea. You could have simply print `c1-1` at the end, to show the count.

---

Thirdly,

```
for (int x = 0; x <= num; x++)
```

you are starting from `0` till equal to `x` that means `0,1,2,3,4,5` total of 6 iterations; not `5`.

If you meant to start from `x = 1`, you need this:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= num; x++)
{            ^
    cout << fibIterative(x) << " ";
    c1++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I agree with you that it is 6 calls for the iterations function, however the question I am solving requires me to show 5, which upon clarifying with the lecturer, he insist it's 5, sighs. That is why I coded the second error you mentioned but I would clarify with the lecturer again about that part as I personally strongly feel its still 6 iterations.

Comment: @Headache : see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). *the first two numbers in the Fibonacci sequence are either 1 and 1, or 0 and 1, depending on the chosen starting point of the sequence*. You had a 0 and 1 starting and was expecting 5 counts. That is why I suspected about it. Now you have referance/ proof. :)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the link! I will use that to clarify with him. Thanks a lot Jejo!

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, I like both answers, its hard to choose, is the green tick very important?